# single or double quotation not being converted by yoeman generator

Tags: double-quotes

" or ' is not being generated in my output file after using yoeman generator! They get converted to &#39 or &#34 instead of " or ' . I have tried using \' ,  \"  and "&quot";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was using <%=texts%> in my model template to get the value. Using <%- texts%> instead fixed the issue.

Previous code was:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var <%= module_name%>Schema = {

......................

<%= texts%>

......................

module.exports = <%=module_name%>;
```

Fixed Code is:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var <%= module_name%>Schema = {

......................

<%-texts%>

......................

module.exports = <%=module_name%>;
```